# How to configure ALB/Traefik/HA Proxy with ECS for multiple websites added by client

Tags: amazon-web-services, haproxy, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs, traefik

I am planning to use IaaC (Terraform vs Ansible yet to decide) to generate Tasks and Clusters in ECS which results in deploying application containers for different websites. Till this point it is sorted but how can I map these websites to containers through ALB/Traefik/HA Proxy or any other service. For limited number of websites, it can be done but websites are added from clients which is not defined.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please mark answer below as answered if this solves your question?

Answer (score 1):

It's rather straight forward, when you generated your services in Terraform for example, you can specify docker-labels in task-definition and they will be picked up by Traefik and added to routing. Something like:

```
"dockerLabels":{
    "traefik.enable":"true",
    "traefik.port":"${portFrom}",
    "traefik.backend":"my-service",
    "traefik.frontend.rule":"Host:app.${var.domain}" },
```